# require does not work in sub directory

Tags: node.js

I am trying to load var `mongoose = require('mongoose');` in a file inside sub directory:

```
model/DB_thingy.js
```

Contents of this file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
console.log(mongoose);
```

But it output: **mongoose is not defined**

But if I try same thing in `app.js`, it it works as usual.

Please tell me why its not working in sub directory ? Do I need to use relative path ?